# Using System.Net.Mail to send email from Database list of user

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mailmessage

I have the following email function that sends an email to a list of users. I add the users with the method `message.To.Add(new MailAddress("UserList@email.com"))`:

```
Using System.Net.Mail

protected void SendMail()
{     

    //Mail notification
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("UserList@email.com"));
    message.Subject = "Email Subject ";
    message.Body = "Email Message";
    message.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@mail.com");

    // Email Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "MyEmail@mail.com";

    //Password of your mail address
    const string fromPassword = "password";

    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object        
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

But, how can I connect to a SQL-Server Db and get the list of users from a table, instead of from this function? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's more than one kind of database, and this is more than one question. Please ask one question at a time.   Why not actually TRY to implement a connection to a database table, and ask a real question?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: First question I assume Yes, Second question: how can I implement the SqlConnection (SQL Server) into this code? Thanks!

Comment: @Jacman  I would look into "Sending Mail from SQL". There is a system sproc that actually does the sending from within SQL instead of .NET. As far as your question about implementing db connection in your code.... there isn't any magical way of adding a db connection to this.  And simply adding a connection wont do what you are trying to do. You can for example open a data reader and run this function for each row returned by your reader.

Comment: what you are wanting to do is actually quite simple you need to create a method or class that will do the majority of the work for you and when sending emails you need to make a method that will populate a `List<string>` of user emails and have a delimiter `|` for example then you can build the SendTo List based on a simple method I can post you a simple method in regards to how to build the Email Function, you need to do the code that returns the email addresses from the database using C# it's not that difficult.. if you want an example of the send email let me know..

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I would personally create a public class with static properties one that reads the App.Config files ConnectionString, for testing add a Pipe Delimited list of email addresses in the App.Config file and I will paste a much easier method that you can use from with your normal project class what I post will be a .cs file class that you can call utilities and it's pretty self explanatory from there give me 1 min to post the example

Comment: I have given you plenty to get you started please let me know once you get the function to retrieve the email addresses and we can see where to go from there if you still need more help.. Thanks

Comment: @MethodMan Sure, I'm testing right now and let you know.

Comment: ok.. also for smtp are you sure you need the SSL try it without and network credentials otherwise you can follow the code to add it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figured it out myself in the most simple way. I hope this help someone else. Thanks to everybody who responded with positive comments, have the ability to think, and use common sense.

```
Using System.Net.Mail

protected void SendMail()
{     

    //Mail notification
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.Subject = "Email Subject ";
    message.Body = "Email Message";
    message.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@mail.com");

    // Email Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "MyEmail@mail.com";

    //Password of your mail address
    const string fromPassword = "password";

    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
    smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string queryString = @"SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM EMAIL WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = EMAIL_ADDRESS";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            var to = new MailAddress(reader["EMAIL_ADDRESS"].ToString());
            message.To.Add(to);

        }

        // Passing values to smtp object        
        smtp.Send(message);

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create this utilities.cs file in your current project and paste in the following code and see how much easier it is to read

```
public class utilities
{  

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString; } //change dbconn to whatever your key is in the config file
    } 

    public static string EmailRecips
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRecips"];//in the config file it would look like this <add key="EmailRecips" value="personA@SomeEmail.com|PersonB@SomeEmail.com|Person3@SomeEmail.com"/>
        }
    }   

    public static string EmailHost //add and entry in the config file for EmailHost 
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"];
        }
    }

    public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body) //add a third param if you want to pass List<T> of Email Address then use `.Join()` method to join the List<T> with a `emailaddr + | emailAddr` etc.. the Join will append the `|` for you if tell look up how to use List<T>.Join() Method
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient(utilities.EmailHost, 25)) 
        using (var message = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress(utilities.FromEmail),
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            //client.EnableSsl = true; //uncomment if you really use SSL
            //client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);    

            foreach (var address in utilities.EmailRecips.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                message.To.Add(address);
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

//if you want to pass a List and join into a single string of Pipe Delimited string to use in the .Split Function then you can change the method signature to take a string and pass in this to the email for example

```
var emailList = string.Join("|", YourList<T>);
```

//then the new email function signature would look like this

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body, string emailList)
```

//then you would replace the .Split method with this

```
foreach (var address in emailList.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot to optimize and generalize the code below - it's as close to your code as possible while doing what you want. It's up to you to figure out how to connect to your database and get the DataReader.Read(). Try -- if you get stuck, ask something specific.

```
Using System.Net.Mail

protected void SendMail()
{     
Dictionary<string,string> recipients = new Dictionary<string,string>
//--select FirstName, Email form MyClients
//while reader.Read(){
  recipients.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]),Convert.ToString(reader[1]));//adds from user to dictionary
//}


//Mail notification


foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in recipients){
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(kvp.Value));


    message.Subject = "Hello,  "+kvp.Key;
    message.Body = "Email Message";
    message.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@mail.com");

    // Email Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "MyEmail@mail.com";

    //Password of your mail address
    const string fromPassword = "password";

    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object        
    smtp.Send(message);
  }
} //This bracket was outside the code box
```

Comment: PS - I didn't really look over the code you provided to make sure it will work. I'm assuming you copied/pasted. If you figure out how to add the recipients and get errors - come back and let us know what's happening.

Comment: there is actually a much easier and cleaner way of doing this and all the OP really needs is an array of delimited email addresses when doing the to

Comment: please read what I have put in the `//` comments it's very straight forward and if you want to read from a database then you would have to create a `List<string> of the email addresses only. then from there you can use the `.Join()` method to join the list with `|` delimiter it much cleaner in the example I posted you need to just create the function that returns a list of email addresses and loop through the dataset etc.. then add the email addresses to the List<T> object and when calling the Send email function add ad the last param in the Method `<List<string> emailList` as a param

Comment: @Shannon Thanks I'll try your solution too.